# I want to get System Messages Channel in discord.js v12

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want to get `SystemChannel`. I am using discord.js v12, this is what I have so far:

```js
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {

// I want to get this channel, not by name
[System Messages Channel][1]

const channel = (getDefaultChannel) 
if(!channel) return;
channel.send(`hello ${member}!`);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the `SystemChannel` by using [`member.guild.systemChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=systemChannel), or [`member.guild.systemChannelID`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=systemChannelID) in case you want the channel's ID, in your `guildMemberAdd` event.

Answer (score 0):

```html
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  // Get the "System Messages Channel"
  const systemMessagesChannel = client.guilds.cache.first().systemChannel;

  // Send a message to the channel
  systemMessagesChannel.send('Hello from the bot!');
});

client.login('YOUR_BOT_TOKEN_HERE');
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).